# Issue with sql trigger not updating fields

Tags: oracle

When choose date from date picker and field pt_date in table pay_tbl is correctly update.
I have added a trigger that should update other fields when date is added:
pt_user, pt_code

The 2 fields not getting updated for the modified record.
Can anyone check & help?

```
CREATE TABLE PAY_AUDIT
(
    idtrack         VARCHAR2(30),
    pt_user         VARCHAR2(30),
    pt_date         DATE,
    pt_code         VARCHAR2(30),
    pt_name         VARCHAR2(30)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PAY_AUDIT_TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE
   ON PAY_AUDIT
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   v_USERNAME VARCHAR2(30);
   V_CODE VARCHAR2(30);

BEGIN

IF :NEW.PT_DATE is null then
SELECT user INTO v_username
   FROM dual;

SELECT CODE into v_code from ORDER_CODE; 
 :new.pt_name := v_username;
 :new.pt_code : v_code;
endif;
```

END;
    /

Comment: That trigger code won't even compile - there are at least three errors that would prevent it. What did you see when you created it - if you did? An invalid trigger ought to cause an exception when you try to update the table...

Comment: It's first time I'm trying to write a trigger am new to pl sql

Comment: wht errors and how to do it?

Comment: You're trying to modify data after it's been updated in the table; you're missing an `end if;`; you're doing a select without an `into` clause, so you never set `v_into` - and that also has no filter so will probably try to fetch multiple values into a scalar variable anyway; the dual table doesn't have a `sign_on` column. I'm not sure what you want it to do.

Comment: i have a table PAY_AUDIT, created a form that reads data from it for user to input pt_date which is the pay_date, once its updated in the table the trigger should update the pt_name i.e the user who has make the date input and also update the pt_code which is take from another table & link by ID

Comment: You need an **before** trigger. And the select on `order_code` needs a `where` clause to make sure you get **exactly** one row from that table. Also the variable `v_username` is useless. You can use `:new.pt_name := user;`